# How to pass reference of an control to another control in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controls

I have a requirement of passing reference of control to another custom control.
I created a custom control which contains a dependency property `associateDatagridProperty`

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        AssociatedDataGridProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AssociatedDatagrid",
            typeof(DataGrid),
            typeof(CustomControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
            );

    public Datagrid AssociatedDatagrid
    {
        get { return (Datagrid )base.GetValue(AssociatedDataGridProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(AssociatedDataGridProperty, value); }
    }
```

In the XAML I'm assigning Value like this

```
<Datagrid x:name=ClientGrid />
```

Here Datagrid is Microsoft WPF toolkit datagrid

```
<CustomControl x:Name="DatagridPaging"  
               Canvas.Left="24"    
               Canvas.Top="236"
               AssociatedDatagrid="{Binding ElementName=clientsGrid ,Path=Name}">
```

When I try to access the value of AssociatedDatagrid property it always shows `null`

Can anyone tell me the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 18):

Here is the code :

First element which will be referenced in the second one :

```
<Label x:Name="aGivenNameLabel" Content="kikou lol"/>
```

The second element :

```
<ContentControl Content={Binding ElementName=aGivenNameLabel}" />
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Path=Name` in your `Binding`. What you end up doing here instead is passing the value of the `Name` property of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Instead of posting another answer (since I agree), I'll just add a note here, in case there's still confusion.  Mainly, behind the scenes, the Binding is trying to do the following:
AssociatedDatagrid = (clientsGrid.Name as Datagrid);
which will come out to null.